# ERROR when try to install cretueusebiu/valet-windows

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

Hi Guys i try to install cretueusebiu/valet-windows, but i found the error like this :
$ composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows
Changed current directory to C:/Users/ROG/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Using version ^2.4 for cretueusebiu/valet-windows
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update cretueusebiu/valet-windows
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- illuminate/container[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/container[v8.12.0, ..., v8.77.1] require psr/container ^1.0 -> found psr/container[1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2] but the package is fixed to 2.0.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.4.0, ..., 2.4.1] require illuminate/container ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v8.0.0, ..., v8.77.1].
- Root composer.json requires cretueusebiu/valet-windows ^2.4 -> satisfiable by cretueusebiu/valet-windows[2.4.0, 2.4.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require cretueusebiu/valet-windows:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require cretueusebiu/valet-windows:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

can anyone help, Thanks

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Consider adding some code formatting to the question so that we can easily identify the output of composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downgrading my php version, thanks All

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31623963)

Answer (score 0):

> illuminate/container[v8.0.0, ..., v8.11.2] **require php ^7.3** -> your **(8.1.1)**

The error is self-explanatory.  The `illuminate/container` package requires PHP version 7.3 or above but not reaching 8.0 or above while you're PHP version is 8.1

If the package doesn't contain breaking changes for PHP 8 you can try installing using `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag like:

`composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 0):

Try to write this code to install...

`composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows --with-all-dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing php under 7.3 in your composer.json, and then run

`composer global require cretueusebiu/valet-windows --with-all-dependencies`

On my next valet install, it usually works for me.